# How can I improve my existing *elementary* questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban, bad-questions

[**Update** 1/5/18] The ban has been lifted now. I have received many constructive helpful comments. This question seems to be obsolete now. I will leave it as what it was here. My question is **not** a duplicate of the linked one: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/758077). Neither the answer there answers my question. I asked it after I read the how-to-ask article *and* after I realized that I did not see a room for improvement for my elementary questions to the best of my knowledge.

---

I am currently banned from asking questions and I am reading the instruction from

https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

I am told to

> Begin by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.

All my questions are *elementary* and they could unavoidably be considered as useless to this site. **I have tried my best to make them well written**.

After reading the article in

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

**I realize that I should not have asked those elementary questions at all in the first place**. But deleting those questions would not help me get rid of the ban.

**Question**: How can I improve my existing elementary questions?

Comment: Yeah that's a tough one. One option is to get some of these questions "disassociated" from your account. They will still exist, but will not be counted as YOUR questions, and won't impact your ban's score.  To request these, you need to use the contact form (that's pretty much all I know about the process, not sure what's needed for these to get dissasociated). Doesn't help you fix your existing, but could still help get you unbanned.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am asking specifically **elementary** questions.

Comment: Trivial (or elementary as you refer to them) questions are not inherently bad or off-topic, in fact some of the most useful questions on the site may be considered trivial to someone versed in the relevant topics.

Comment: Here are two questions of yours that could be edited to fit the [ask] guidelines better, and may be good enough, even being elementary, to flip to positive scores. You'd only need two upvotes to flip them. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276187/how-can-i-write-a-pseudo-code-for-the-following-diagram), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805705/functions-defined-by-inline-with-vector-input-in-matlab)

Comment: I think your question are all well-worded as of now. Just wait and see if someone thinks it looks good and upvotes. Sorry but I know nothing about Java and Matlab so I can't judge them.

Comment: Huh. This user has now [more than doubled his non-association-bonus rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758077/jack?tab=reputation) via the Meta effect - including through receiving upvotes on questions with explicitly-labelled *"edit"* blocks and a question with a large passage from a book quoted as an image. Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10276187/1709587) really deserve 2 upvotes? This is silly, and is clearly user-targeted voting, which is against the rules. We shouldn't be rewarding question-banned users who come to Meta by arbitrarily sprinkling upvotes over their post history.

Comment: Aside: in case you don't believe @TinyGiant's comment, I'll note that I've twice asked questions about a language within half an hour of learning how to write "Hello, World!" in it, and those questions have both been well received ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30424935/1709587), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47222968/1709587)). Askers frequently suffer from the delusion that their questions are badly-received because they're beginner-level questions, but that's nonsense. Rather, they're badly received because they're *bad* questions.

Comment: @MarkAmery: "Askers frequently suffer from the delusion that their questions are badly-received because they're beginner-level questions, but that's nonsense" Sorry, but I **don't** have such "nonsense delusion". I am **not** complaining about the fact that my questions in the main site are badly-received.

Comment: @MarkAmery: The reason I raised this question in meta is because I was banned from asking questions, I read the instruction and I would like to learn further how to do the improvement. Any *constructive* comments are sincerely welcomed. "This is silly, and is clearly user-targeted voting, which is against the rules". Thanks, but constructive advices would be much more useful/appreciated then plainly demeaning a 5-year-old question of mine.

Comment: As I can read from your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery?tab=questions&sort=newest), you are certainly very experienced in asking questions. I would certainly appreciate a demonstration on how an expert, as you are, would phrase the question I received "silly" upvotes so that it would be a well-received question.

Comment: @Jack You specifically came here to say that your problem is that you have questions that are elementary.  That's not your problem.  A question being elementory doesn't make it low quality.  A question being unclear, too broad, opinion based, poorly researched, incomplete, not containing a reproducible example, etc. are some of the things that make a question low quality.

Comment: @Servy: This is not a duplicate. I'm specifically asking about how to improve my elementary questions. "A question being elementary doesn't (necessarily) make it low quality." I agree. That is **exactly** why I believe I can still have a chance to improve them in a reasonable amount of time. I come here to ask is because **in my level of expertise, I have tried my best to make them well written** and since they are not up to the standard of this site yet.

Comment: @Servy: you may be very experienced in asking questions. I would certainly appreciate a demonstration on how an expert, as you are, would phrase the question I received "silly" upvotes so that it would be a well-received question. Constructive advices would be much more useful/appreciated then plainly demeaning my questions.

Comment: @Jack Your questions being elementary is irrelevant.  It's like someone asking how to get out of their question ban when they've asked their questions on Wednesday.  It's irrelevant.

Comment: @Servy: I disagree. It is relevant.

Comment: @Jack You've been told by numerous people that *you* consider experts that it's not.  You wanted our expertise, and there you have it.  Given that you feel that you *aren't* an expert on the matter, and also given that you're question banned for your consistently problematic question asking, consider accepting that statement even if you would disagree with it.  Don't focus on how easy or hard the questions are, focus on those things that you've been told matter, and the things that the help center section on how to ask a good question tell you matter.

Comment: @Servy: "focus on those things that you've been told matter, and the things that the help center section on how to ask a good question tell you matter." That is what I am doing.

Comment: @Jack But it's not.  You're focusing purely on the fact that your questions are elementary, saying that that's the important element, and that it makes your questions special form all of the other information out there on what to do in your situation.  It's not.  It's irrelevant.

Comment: @Servy: you linked question and the answers there do not help. This is not a duplicate of that one. Sorry, I disagree with you.

Comment: @Servy: I have explicitly said in my post that  "After reading the article in
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
I realize that I should not have asked those elementary questions at all in the first place. But deleting those questions would not help me get rid of the ban." I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @MarkAmery The question that you linked to that got two up votes was one of the two I had linked to saying it could be edited to be improved, and you are right, it still hasn't been improved by the author (Another user edited it to improve its grammar, but it didn't improve the actual question like the OP could have) , I'm disappointed at the upvotes.